# Mediatek driver installation issue

Tags: drivers, make

I'm trying to install the mt7630e driver on my system(ubuntu 18.04) but on typing the `sudo ./install` command I'm getting this:

```
rahit@Eleven:~/MT7630E-release$ sudo ./install
[sudo] password for rahit: 
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/home/rahit/MT7630E-release/rt2x00 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/rahit/MT7630E-release/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/rahit/MT7630E-release/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/rahit/MT7630E-release/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/rahit/MT7630E-release/rt2x00' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/rahit/MT7630E-release/rt2x00] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
rahit@Eleven:~/MT7630E-release$
```

what should I do?

I downloaded the driver from github- https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1029704/edit) your question and add a link to the sources which you are trying to compile. Otherwise we can not help you.

Answer (score 3):

The module compiles normally on my clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64-bit) with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic libelf-dev dkms
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
cd MT7630E

sudo ./install
sudo make dkms
```

Comment: So you can [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) my answer.

Comment: not working at all.